# Один класс для юзера и админа

Tags: ооп, архитектура

Давно хотел узнать как правильно реализовывать классы где есть несколько ролей пользователей.

Я делаю так:

таблица имеет 3 поля:

**id** | **user_id** | **post**

```
class Posts {
    function add($post, $user_id){
        // добавим пост в бд 
    }

    function fetch($user_id = null){
        if($user_id !== null){
            // получаем все посты конкретного юзера
        } else {
            // получаем ВСЕ посты 
        }
    }

    function delete($post_id, $user_id = null){
        if($user_id !== null){
            // удаляем пост конкретного юзера
            // WHERE user_id = $user_id AND post_id = $post_id
        } else {
            // удаляем любой пост
        }
    }
}

$Posts = new Posts;

// получение всех постов юзера 
$user_id = 10;
$Posts->fetch($user_id);

// админ может получить все посты, вызвав метод без параметров
$Posts->fetch();

// юзер может удалять только свои посты
// даже если сменит $post_id на любое (не свое) значение
$post_id = 3; // прилетает из $_POST
$user_id = 10; // не имеет возможность сменить (например получено из сессии)
$Posts->delete($post_id, $user_id);

// админ может удалить пост любого юзера
// просто упустив второй параметр метода
$post_id = 3;
$Posts->delete($post_id);
```

Правильно ли так?

Comment: я бы разделил пользователя и админа, наследуя админа от класса пользователя (ведь админ такой же пользователь, как и другие, только с расширенными правами). В админе реализовал бы методы *delete, edit* и т.п. В результате, на этапе авторизации определил бы, кто вошел (админ или юзер). Создал бы объект соответствующего класса и избежал бы необходимости в каждой функции проверять, кто нажал кнопку: админ или юзер.

Answer (score 2):

А что вы будете делать в случае, если у вас появится роль модератора, который сможет удалять посты только определённого числа пользователей?

Как правило любая RBAC (Role Based Access Control - управление на основании ролей) строиться на 3 состовляющих: роль, правило и пользователь. В общем случае это:
правило - описывает действие в системе (удаление, создание чего-либо и тп),
роль - совокупность разрешенных правил в системе,
пользователь - сущность, которой принадлежит одна или несколько ролей.

Исходя из этого вы должны выстроить архитектуру таким образом, чтобы у вашего User был условный метот (функция)
`

```
$rule = Rule('deletePost'); // "грубый" пример

if ($user->checkAccess($rule)) 
{ 
    $post->delete(); 
}
```

`

Под капотом метод (функция) `checkAccess($rule): bool` должна содержать проверку: получаем список ролей пользователя и проверяем, можно ли пользователю с такими ролями делать данное действие (принадлежность правила данной роли)

Добавьте в вашей БД такие сущности как: rule, user, role, users_roles (принадлежность пользователей к ролям), roles_rules (принадлежность правил к ролям). А в основном коде к постам выполняйте лишь проверку

Comment: В принципе я так и делаю. `class PostController {
 
 
 function delete(){
  
  $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  
  if($User->is_admin() || $User->is_moderator()){
   $Posts->delete($post_id)
  } else if($User->is_user()){
   $Posts->delete($post_id, $User->id)
  }
  
 }
 
}`

Comment: @Deniel нет, вы делаете не так. Ответ, в принципе, грамотный, но есть два НО. 1) уж очень сумбурно - понять суть можно только если знаешь, о чем речь 2) такая архитектура хороша в больших проектах. Для самопальной админки с тремя ролями и пятью правилами оно сильно излишне

Comment: с правилами как раз непонятно. У меня сейчас у модератора такие же права как и у админа. Но хотелось бы как то разграничить права. Что бы админ мог назначить привилегии модератору.

Comment: @Deniel следуйте принципу: проверять не роль, а проверять правило. В вашем случае вы проверяете "если пользователь администратор или модератор, то...". Выстройте приложение так, чтобы проверяли "если пользователь может удалять запись, то...", а под капотом уже проверяйте исходя из каких ролей он может или не может сделать это действие.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо что обьяснили на пальцх. Теперь мне понятно как организовать разграничение прав.

получилось что то вроде этого

```
class User {

    // упрощенно
    function checkAccess($rule){

        $user_rules = unserialize($db->query("SELECT rules FROM users WHERE user_id = {$this->user_id}"));

        if(in_array($rule, $user_rules)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


class PostController {

    function delete(){

        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        // админ 
        if($User->checkAccess('delete_any_posts')){
            $Posts->delete($post_id)
        } 

        // юзер
        else if($User->checkAccess('delete_OWN_posts')){
            $Posts->delete($post_id, $User->id)
        }

    }

}
```

Но все таки сделать универсальный метод не получится.

```
$Posts->delete($post_id, $User->id)
```

Для того что бы юзер не смог удалить не свой пост, нужно передавать ID юзера в метод.